# how to obtain table check on (if) condition basis

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an attendance system where users could go in and out the campus, I finished it with this condition:

```
if($i == 0){
    $in = '&#10004;';
    $out = '';
}
if($i > 0){
    if (strtotime(substr($arr[$i][0],0,10)) == strtotime(substr($arr[$i-1][0],0,10))) {
        $count++;
        if($count % 2 == 0){
            $in = '&#10004;';
            $out = '';
        }
        else{
            $in = '';
            $out = '&#10004;';
        }
    }
    else{
        $count = 0;
        $in = '&#10004;';
        $out = '';
    }
}
```

However, I was instructed to add a break-in and break-out.

I'm using a hardware wherein it has a database on MS SQL. The types set are:

Type = 1 is In, Type = 2 is Out, Type = 4 is Break Out, and Type = 8 is Break In.

I'm trying to get it using this:

```
$query = 'SELECT ActualTime, Type FROM TA3.dbo.TimeLogs WHERE TimeLogs.EmployeeID='.$passed.' ORDER BY TimeLogs.ActualTime 
$stmt = $conn->query($query);
$stmt->execute();
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (isset($_POST['Type'])
{
  $Type = $_POST['Type'];
}
if($Type == 1)
{
$in = '&#10004;';
$bin = '';
$bout = '';
$out = '';
}
if($Type == 2)
{
$in = '';
$bin = '';
$bout = '';
$out = '&#10004;';
}
if($Type == 4)
{
$in = '';
$bin = '';
$bout = '&#10004;';
$out = '';
}
if($Type == 8)
{
$in = '';
$bin = '&#10004;';
$bout = '';
$out = '';
}
else
{
$in = '&#10004;';
$bin = '';
$bout = '';
$out = '';
}
```

However, I'm not getting any checks on my table.

Comment: Are you sure you getting value in $_POST['Type']?

Comment: Actually, I'm not. I tried getting the value of $_POST Type but I get no return using var_dump.